# Math Symbol in Equation

Tags: education

I want to ask, what is the meaning of this symbol in red circle?

[image]

Comment: It is a "one" meaning "Characteristic function" (or "indicator function) of the set placed as the index : 1 on this set, 0 outside; sometimes the alternative 1/0 is meant as true/false.

Comment: It's standard notation for the characteristic function.  In your case, for, say, the up-and-in option, it is $1$ if the asset price ever got to $B$ or greater and it is $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is a characteristic or an indicator function. Exact description of this function you can find e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function.